# npm install github repo to every repo in sub folder

Tags: reactjs, bash, npm-install

I have multiple React repos cloned from gitlab within my `work` folder. I want to implement a work-wide eslint configuration, whereby every project has the same eslint rules. As such, I want to first `npm install eslint@7 --save-dev`every repo  (this repo comes with React best-practice eslint recommendations).
Is there way to npm install for every repo once from one folder above? I don't want to install it globally.
I will then use a bash script to add a eslintrc file to each repo at root level.
example of repos:

```
work dir
├── react-app-one
├── react-app-two
├── app-three
├── app-four
├── app-five
```

Answer (score 1):

Look at npm [workspaces](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/workspaces) since this does exactly what you ask for